# MvvmCross object data binding

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am new to MvvmCross, I have a question with regards to binding in Android. I can bind to single property but unable to data bind to an object. Not sure what I am doing wrong but here it is:

**Model class:**

```
 public class Login : MvxNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _email;

    public string Email
    {
        get { return _email; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _email, value);
        }
    }

    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**Snippet of View Model Class:**

```
public class LoginOptionViewModel: MvxViewModel
{

    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;

    public LoginOptionViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;

        LoginCommand =
            new MvxAsyncCommand(async () => await _navigationService.Navigate<RegistrationViewModel>());

    }

    public IMvxAsyncCommand LoginCommand { get; set; }

    private Login _loginInfo;

    public Login LoginInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return _loginInfo ?? new Login();
        }
        set
        {
            _loginInfo = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => LoginInfo);
        }
    }

}
```

**Snippet of Android Axml:**

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/loginEmailTxt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/EmailHint"
                android:textColor="@color/darkNavy"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                local:MvxBind="Text LoginInfo.Email" />
```

Where am I going wrong, I have placed a breakpoint but do not see it being hit. This is binded to EditText but nothing appears to happen. Am I missing or doing something wrong in order to bind to an object property ?

Answer (score 2):

> MvvmCross object data binding

You could implement the `MvxNotifyPropertyChanged` interface, so the system could notifies clients that a property value has changed.

Modify your object to :

```
public class Login : MvxNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _email;
    public string Email
    {
        get => _email;
        set => SetProperty(ref _email, value);
    }
}
```

In the `MainViewModel` :

```
private Login _login;
public Login Login
{
    get
    {
        return _login ?? new Login() { Email = "=-="};
    }
    set
    {
        _login = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Login);
    }
}
```

Then use it in `axml` :

```
local:MvxBind="Text Login.Email"
```

It works fine on my side.

**Update :**

I cant reproduce your problem, but here is my complete code, hope this can help you :

```
public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
    }

    public override Task Initialize()
    {
        return base.Initialize();
    }

    public IMvxCommand ResetTextCommand => new MvxCommand(ResetText);
    private void ResetText()
    {
        Text = "Hello MvvmCross";
    }

    private string _text = "Hello MvvmCross";
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _text, value); }
    }

    private Login _login;
    public Login Login
    {
        get
        {
            return _login ?? new Login() { Email = "=-="};
        }
        set
        {
            _login = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Login);
        }
    }
}

public class Login : MvxNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _email;
    public string Email
    {
        get => _email;
        set => SetProperty(ref _email, value);
    }
}
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZloMD.png).

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback, I have done what you mentioned but its still not working? does it help by mentioning that I have a separate solution for the Model ? also on the viewmodel if i set a property like you have for Email = "=-=" it breaks the app for some reason.

Comment: @helloworld, I have update my answer, you may check it.

Comment: I have a feeling its due to seperate solution which it unables to hold same reference of MVVM. I think ill place domain into same solution and its most likely to work then

Comment: Would you mind sharing your project, to make sure we are verifying the exact same thing you are using ?

Comment: I've noticed it is working i.e. if i place breakpoint in the Login class at the property of Email it raises event and the breakpoint does hit. However, how comes the breakpoint does not work from the ViewModel class when i put breakpoint on the object of Login ?

Comment: @helloworld, that's weird, it should be fired, could you please post your complete code ?

Comment: Hi i have updated the question section with the codebase as requested. Please let me know where I'm going wrong. Thanks :)